# Audio playback prevents standby

Tags: windows-7, standby, energy-saving

Playing back audio (actually it's the driver, not the specific application used) keeps my Windows 7 system from going to standby - any way to change this behaviour? While it might be useful in general, I'd like to change it for me. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can set this in `Power options` in `Control panel`.

1. <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> -> `powercfg.cpl`
2. Slect at your active power plan: `Change plan settings`
3. Slect `Change advanced power settings`
4. In `multimedia settings`, set `When sharing media` to `Allow the computer to sleep`

[image]

Comment: thank you, but I have to say that I am playing back media diretly on my system, it's not being streamed. The options you mentioned seems to affect streamin/sharing only, anyway will give it a try ;-)